# Generate automatically ids starting with 1000 in Loopback

Tags: postgresql, loopbackjs

I want to generate ids for a model automatically in Loopback so that first id is 1001, then 1002, 1003... and so on. Important is, that all ids are over 1000.

I've tried adding a thousand to id values in before save and after save operation hooks, but in before hook the id property is not defined and in after hook the change is not saved. I'm using postgresql.

How can I do this?

My model definition in externalorder.json is:

```
{
  "name": "Externalorder",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": false,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "postgresql": {
    "schema": "public",
    "table": "externalorder"
  },
  "properties": {
    "externalorderId": {
      "type": "number",
      "id": true,
      "generated": true,
      "required": false,
      "length": null,
      "precision": 32,
      "scale": 0,
      "postgresql": {
        "columnName": "externalorder_id",
        "dataType": "integer",
        "dataLength": null,
        "dataPrecision": 32,
        "dataScale": 0,
        "nullable": "NO"
      },
      "_selectable": false,
      "comments": "tilausnumero"
    },
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using defaults id generated from 0, you can use globally unique ids. Those are big strings, always unique. Maybe you can also use type: number for the id, never tested it.

```
 {
  "name": "Externalorder",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true, // Set to true
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "postgresql": {
    "schema": "public",
    "table": "externalorder"
  },
  "properties": {
    "containerId": {
      "defaultFn" : "guid", // use globally unique id
      "type": "string"
    },
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, though it doesn't really solve my issue since I specifically need id numbers that start with 1000.